# Creating FollowMe link SoundCloud

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a simple FollowMe link for our Company and I am having a problem with the case when a user does not allow pop-ups. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: '***********************',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8002/callback.html'
  });
  var isCalled = false;
  var connect = function (){
    isCalled = true;
    SC.connect(function(){
      SC.put('/me/followings/123456', function(me, error){
        console.log('me: ', me)
        console.log('error: ', error)
        window.location.replace("http://www.soundcloud.com");
      });
    });
  };
  $('a').click(function(){
    isCalled = true;
    connect();
  });
  if(!isCalled){
    console.log(isCalled);
    //console.log('connect called')
    isCalled = true;
    connect();
  }
});
```

Currently if you allow pup-ups in the browser you properly follow the desired user however when the user blocks popups and clicks the link they get the following error in the dialog box.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost:8002/ from frame with URL http://soundcloud.monstercat.com/callback.html?code=79e58c1c4ee8b3fb2a1c935fb676da90&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_1c798#access_token=1-24501-24540735-ab27bed0d285f42&scope=non-expiring. Domains, protocols and ports must match. callback.html:6

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectCallback' of undefined callback.html:6

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://soundcloud.monstercat.com/callback.html?code=79e58c1c4ee8b3fb2a1c935fb676da90&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_1c798#access_token=1-24201-27645735-ab27bed0d285f42&scope=non-expiring from frame with URL http://soundcloud.monstercat.com/callback.html?code=79e58c1c4ee8b3fb2a1c935fb676da90&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_1c798#access_token=1-24201-27645735-ab27bed0d285f42&scope=non-expiring. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: callback.html is the standard one from the soundcloud dev site.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `connect` (and hence, trying to follow yourself) immediately upon page load. This is why the popup is being blocked. Unless the popup happens immediately while handling a click event, the browser will block it. **Remove** this part from the end of that script:

```
  if(!isCalled){
    console.log(isCalled);
    //console.log('connect called')
    isCalled = true;
    connect();
  }
```